# Is there delegation in foxpro?

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I am very new to foxpro and have to to some job. My question is in the title. Is there delegation in foxpro? Can I send a function as a parameter?

Edit:

Unfortunately there are lots of duplicates in code in the project I work. For example there are thousands of items in a collection. Code is iterating and doing some job for every 100 item. This some job may be sending e-mail, sending sms, writing in a file and save the file, paging etc. In the code for each job there is a loop (everytime checking if a local `count` variable equals to 100) and makes the job if the count is equal to 100 (At the end making the same job for the remainings also). My intention is to create a generic method doing this algorithm. Its parameters will be the collection, a delegate function (and maybe an integer referring 100 in my example above).

Comment: No delegation that I am aware of such as in C# that you can expose "events".  You CAN add hooks to windows messages.  Can you clarify what you are TRYING to attempt?

Comment: There are other tricks to simulate, but not sure how to offer as a solution without a better understanding of what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @DRapp thank you. I have made an edit in the question clarifying my intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EVALUATE(), EXECSCRIPT() and & to execute function calls and/or other bits of code contained in strings.  You'd have to weigh the security concerns of executing arbitrary code that way, of course.  You can't pass a function as a parameter, but can pass its name as a string and then invoke it using the commands I mentioned.

Comment: thank you. I did not know that there is a way to evaluate strings. I will study these functions.